# How to redirect packagemaker log file output

Tags: macos, packagemaker

While an installer (built via packagemaker) is running ... from the menu, we can select `Window > Installer Log` and then choose to `Save` it ... but this is not something that can be asked of all those who run the installer.

The installation itself is supposed to be a hands-off simple process. But in case something goes wrong and we need to go back and dig through logs, it would be great to configure packagemaker or the installer it produces ... to spit out the log file everytime it runs.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/var/log/install.log` is written by Installer, and contains information about the packages being installed, pre-install / post-install scripts being executed, and any errors that occur along the way.

Comment: Thank You! How did you come by this golden nugget of knowledge? Are there some PackageMaker docs somewhere whose link you could share?

Comment: The man page for the `installer` command mentions it. I'm not particularly familiar with PackageMaker so I'm not sure if there is any documentation on it which points at this log.